# undefined reference to `xlCreateBookW'

Tags: c++, qt, libxl

While using the libxl library in QT(c++) I got this error

```
undefined reference to `xlCreateBookW'
```

I have tried the setup in their website, https://www.libxl.com/setup.html
I added :

```
INCLUDEPATH = C:\libxl-4.0.4.0\include_cpp  
LIBS += C:\libxl-4.0.4.0\lib\libxl.lib
```

to my `project.pro` and the file `bin/libxl.dll` to the project directory. It didn't work instead the error show up, how can I solve it please?
the code is in here https://www.libxl.com/home.html , i don't know i couldn't add it

Comment: You have not shown your code using xlCreateBookW. Also, are you using QtCreator?

Comment: think you for your feedback , i added the link of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem actually the customer support guy i emailed him,
he told me to choose the bin which has the same version of my compiler (mine is 64bit) so you have to choose the bin and the lib also the same version and the path:

for my case (Qt_6_2_3_MinGW_64_bit compiler )
`INCLUDEPATH = C:/libxl-4.0.4.0/include_cpp`
`LIBS += C:/libxl-4.0.4.0/lib64/libxl.lib`
in the .pro file also  you have to copy the `libxl.dll` from
`C:\libxl-4.0.4.0\bin64` (for my case)

and thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).